# Evaluate the complex integral $\oint_{|z|=1} z^3\cos z~\mathrm dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, line-integrals

$$\oint_{|z|=1} z^3\cos z~\mathrm dz$$

I tried using $z=r\mathrm e^{i\theta}$, but the integral gets very complicated before evaluating at the bounds. Was this not the right approach?

Also, what should I make of $|z|=1$? I interpreted that as the radius of $z$ being 1 and, because it doesn't specify the angle, all angles between $0$ and $2\pi$, inclusive.

Answer (score 4):

$f(z) = z^3 \cos z$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C$, and $|z| = 1$ is a closed path. Hence, by using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, $\oint_{|z| = 1} f(z) dz = 0$

Comment: Is $|z|=1$ a closed path because it is a vector? Furthermore, would that vector include the origin?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat by $|z| = 1$ I mean $\{ z \in \Bbb C \mid |z| = 1\}$, i.e. the unit circle.

Comment: Ah ok. So when I plot $z^3cosz$ alongside the unit circle, I see that we are basically talking about a circle centered at the origin with radius of 1 and a line that runs from Q3 to Q1. What, then, is the concept behind Cauchy's Integral Theorem in regards to this plot? [See this Wolfram plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot(f(z)%3Dz%5E3cosz)+where+-1+%3C+z+%3C1)

Comment: @whatwhatwhat this has nothing to do with $z^3 \cos z$; replace it with any other function that is holomorphic on some simply connected domain containing the circle and you get the same result. I suggest that you read the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem