# Evaluate the line integral $\oint_C \frac{e^z}{(z+1)^2}\, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, line-integrals

$$\oint_C \frac{e^z}{(z+1)^2}\, dz,\quad C: |z-1|=3$$

My attempt:
I think that this integral $\neq 0$ because the curve is a disc. If it were a circle, then by Cauchy's Integral Theorem this integral would be $=0$. I think the next step would be to find a way to describe this disc in term of a parameter $t$. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you know of residues yet?

Comment: Do you understand what Cauchy's integral theorem actually states?

Comment: @ChristopherHalverson according to my professor, no, but Google is a thing. Is it applicable here?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "the curve is a disc"?

Comment: @okrzysik if holomorphic and the curve is closed, then the integral is zero.

Comment: @T.Bongers $|z-1|=3$ is a disc, is it not?

Comment: Why do think $C$ is a disc?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Yes it is.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal well $|z-1|$ is the distance from $z$ to the point $(1,0i)$. But $z$ can be any point in the complex plane, the only criteria being that it must be 3 units away from $(1,0i)$. So at first guess it would seem like it's a circle, but I think my professor said the center is not included. Thus, a disc and not a circle. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat it's funny you mention "if it were a circle" when it obviously IS a circle.

Comment: @cpiegore why is it a circle? How would you express a disc in the complex plane?

Comment: Now I'm *really* confused...

Comment: @whatwhatwhat For complex numbers a circle is any set of the form {$z \in C: |z - a| = b$} where $a$ is any complex number and $b$ is a positive real number

Comment: @cpiegore Ah ok.

Comment: By the way what theorem in complex variables says if C is disc then the integral does not equal  0?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal [I based it off this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664964/evaluate-the-complex-integral-oint-z-1-z3-cos-z-mathrm-dz/1664967?noredirect=1#comment3396274_1664967). Someone commented that because the function was holomorphic and because the "curve" was the unit circle, then the integral evaluates to zero. The difference was that I thought this problem's curve was a disc and also because the answer to this problem is given ($2\pi ie^{-1}$), so I reasoned that the difference was the disc and thus is not equal to zero. But it looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $\oint_C$ is *not* referring to a surface integral. We're not integrating over a disc. In the context of your question, $\oint_C$ is referring to a *closed path integral* along the path named $C$.

Your integrand has a singularity only at $z=-1$, which is *inside* the region bounded by $C$. If you have yet to learn the Residue Theorem, you may apply [Cauchy's Integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula#Theorem) instead:

$$\oint_C \frac{e^z}{(z+1)^2}\, dz = \frac{2\pi i}{1!}\frac{d}{dz}e^z\bigg|_{z=-1}= 2\pi ie^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the only singularity of $\;f(z)=\frac{e^z}{(z+1)^2}\;$ within the domain enclosed by the given contour is a double pole at $\;z=-1\;$ , so

$$\oint_{|z-1|=3}f(z)\,dz=2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}(f)|_{z=-1}\;,\;\;\;\text{and}$$

$$\text{Res}(f)|_{z=-1}=\frac d{dz}\left((z+1)^2f(z)\right)'=\left.e^z\right|_{z=-1}=\frac1e$$

so

$$\oint_{|z-1|=3}f(z)\,dz=\frac{2\pi i}e$$